# Superman comic which had a drawing style of the Animated Series

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics

I've seen some comics where the style of drawing was like in the cartoon TV series (*The Superman Animated Series*). What was the name of those comics (for example, *Action Comics* or *The Adventures of Superman*...) or what issues of certain series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Superman Adventures"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_Adventures)

> Superman Adventures is a DC Comics comic book series featuring
>   Superman. It is different from other Superman titles because it is set
>   in the continuity (and style) of "Superman: The Animated Series" as
>   opposed to the regular DC Universe.